# sed to replace matching word to end of line

Tags: sed, string, tcsh

I am trying to remove all characters after particular match pattern i.e `nfin` to the end of line.

### sample_text

```
xxsac00mi126 vddai:f1042 tkeept_iph xsac00.f1040 vdda lvtpfet m=1 nf=1 nfin=2 pdej=1.6e-07 asej=3.2e-16 lrsd=4e-08 pre_layout_local=0
```

### Command

```
sed -i "s/nfin\=[0-9].*//g" sample_text
```

### Desired Output

```
xxsac00mi126 vddai:f1042 tkeept_iph xsac00.f1040 vdda lvtpfet m=1 nf=1 nfin=2
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this `sed` instead:

```
sed -E 's/ pdej.*$//'
```

Example:

```
sed -E 's/ pdej.*$//' file.txt 
xxsac00mi126 vddai:f1042 tkeept_iph xsac00.f1040 vdda lvtpfet m=1 nf=1 nfin=2
```

Where `file.txt` contains:

```
cat file.txt 
xxsac00mi126 vddai:f1042 tkeept_iph xsac00.f1040 vdda lvtpfet m=1 nf=1 nfin=2 pdej=1.6e-07 asej=3.2e-16 lrsd=4e-08 pre_layout_local=0
```

**OR:**
If you want (need) to use `nfin` as an anchor of sorts, use:

```
sed -E 's/(.*nfin=[0-9]).*/\1/' file.txt 
xxsac00mi126 vddai:f1042 tkeept_iph xsac00.f1040 vdda lvtpfet m=1 nf=1 nfin=2
```

Comment: I was looking for `nfin` as anchor mainly.  The above command works fine ; can I use `inline` argument ?

Comment: If you want to match the **last** "nfin" use `(.*nfin=...)` -- if you want to match the **first** "nfin", omit the leading `.*` -> `(nfin=...)`

Comment: Answer can be improved by making more self-documenting by replacing `-E` with or adding `--regexp-extended` in examples.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i "/nfin=[0-9]/{s//&\n/;P;d;}" sample_text
```

will remove the rest of line after `nfin=[0-9]`
For line(s) with `nfin=[0-9]`:

- put `\n`ewline after the pattern (`&`)
- `P`rint line before `\n`ewline
- `d`elete line (print any more)

Comment: Could you please explain a bit, why your answer solves the problem? This is a knowledge base, so other users might benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -ne 's/[ ]nfin=[^ ]*/&\n/;P' < your_spice_netlist
```

But you have to keep in mind that spice netlists can have instances('x') or for that matter any element cross line boundaries and in such a scenario the above sed code might not work as maybe the nfin parameter might lie at the beginning of a line, like as, +nfin=23. Also, sometimes 'nfin' might appear parameterized, e.g., nfin='width*0.5 + 1./nfac*len', whereby the nfin=[0-9]
will not match.

However if you can assure that there are no multilines (at least for instances) then the above should work reliably. Also there be no TABs.